# "There was a problem communicating with Google servers, try again later" error

Tags: google-play-store, google, google-play-services

Yet another occurrence of this when setting up a new phone, in this case a OnePlus 5 with the H2OS (Chinese) OS.  I installed the current Oxygen OS official 9.0.9 from XDA, used the OnePlus transfer, and despite many strategies, could not get rid of this error.
I tried:

Wiping the cache, other data in Google Play
Ditto other Google services
turned off WIFI, turned on, etc.
Reboot
Reinstalled Google play
Installed Google APK from APK store

I had seen these elsewhere working for some folks.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange. So, you are trying to self-answer your post? The parts should be separated into distinct 'Q' & 'A' posts, however. Please see [Help](https://android.stackexchange.com/help) for the proper context of each. Possibly also the [tour](https://android.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! On SE sites, it's perfectly fine to [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) (also [see here](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question)) – but answers should be posted as answers, not as part of the question-post. Mind [edit]ing that out of your question, and move it to a separate answer? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the only thing that worked for me was doing a factory reset.
Hope one of these approaches works for others!
Having more potential solutions in your tool box increases your chances of success.

YMMV  "Good luck, Jim!"

Answer (score 0):

I have come up against this problem today, and have found a solution when everything I found online failed to fix it.

The problem I had was that all Google apps weren't working. Chrome would not load pages, I could not add an account (hung on Checking Info and eventually gave the error "
There was a Problem Communicating with Google Servers"), GMail app would load but would not show emails etc.

I found that the version of Chrome I had was a long way behind. I went into Setting/Apps and disabled Chrome. This basically re-enabled Android System Webview, and at this point I could then re-add an account, Gmail and the Play Store started working.  I could then use Play Store to re-enable and then update Chrome, which then worked too. If you want to, you can then go into Developer Mode and set Chrome back as the Webview Implementation.

I hope this helps someone avoid spending the hours I did on this issue!